# Qt FATAL: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted (core dumped) in Ubuntu 16.04 Server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04 Server Core 
I want to execute virtualbox in Ubuntu but it has error
how can I do?

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed a Server version of Ubuntu it has only a console mode.

You can proceed with X11-server-based GUI. There are several light weight desktop environments that may work better than a standard Gnome or KDE environment.
such as

1. Openbox
2. Fluxbox

Please refer this [ubuntu.com/ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI) for more information

Comment: Another possible solution is to forward the the x11 session via ssh

Answer (score 0):

on the bash console:

`echo $(vboxmanage --version)`

should work.